# How to automate cleanup of Rails 6 Webpack public packs folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

While using Webpacker in my Rails 6 application to manage javascript or assets, I have noticed that the `public/packs` folder is pilling up with compiled files. Webpack assets from `public/packs` folder usually occupy a lot of disk space. Is there any way to automate `public/packs` folder cleanup?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches as [mentioned](https://rubyinrails.com/2019/04/18/rails-webpack-public-packs-clean-up-assets) in the post.

**1. Use webpack clobber rake task.**

```rb
bundle exec rails webpacker:clobber
```

This will clean up directory that is use for outputting compiled webpack assets. But, again this is a manual effort and we need to invoke this rake task often to clean up disk space.

**2. Use clean-webpack-plugin**

Add clean-webpack-plugin as given below.

```
yarn add -D clean-webpack-plugin
```

And add this plugin to development.js.

```js
# webpack/development.js
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin")
const path = require("path")
const environment = require("./environment")

environment.plugins.append(
  "CleanWebpackPlugin",
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(["packs"], {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../public"),
    verbose: true
  })
)
module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```